# Populate second <select> drop down based on the first <select> drop down option

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to populate my second  drop down based on the first selected drop down option.

Here's my work so far:

**form.php** - I used *javascript* to call **getgeneral.php**. Second drop down will show up when user has chosen from the (first) *drop down*:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_states() { // Call to ajax function
    var classitem = $('#classitem').val();
    var dataString = "classitem="+classitem;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getgeneral.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#get_general").html(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST">

<?php 

include('conn.php');

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM classtable");

?>

<select id="classitem" name="classitem" onchange="get_states();">
<option value=''>Select</option>
<?php 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['genclasscode'] . "'>" . $row['description'] . "</option>";}

?>
</select>

<div id="get_general"></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the **getgeneral.php** where it will fetch data based from the first drop down list:

```
<?php

include('conn.php');

if ($_POST) {
    $classitem = $_POST['classitem'];
    if ($classitem != '') {

       $result1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM generalclass WHERE genclasscode='$classitem'");

       echo "<select name='classitem'>";
       echo "<option value=''>Select</option>"; 
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
          echo "<option value='" . $row['specclassid'] . "'>" . $row['description'] . "</option>";}
       echo "</select>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo  '';
    }
}

?>
```

**PROBLEM**: *Second drop down* won't show up. There's no error showing up when I run **form.php**

Comment: Can you check your network requests when changing the first value? It will sometimes tell you an error that will not output. Hit `F12` after you open the page and then capture the request

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: you forgot to include jquery, or you have a conflict. Looks like the former if the code is complete

Comment: Did you include the jQuery libraries in your `<head>` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for getting back on this question too late.

The problem is that I forgot to include the **jQuery** in my code.

I include **jQuery** like this, between the `<head> </head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Thank you to *Bryan* and *Chitowns24* on their comments above.